# Getting duplicate data in Angular HTML table (PrimeNG)

Tags: html, angular, laravel, typescript, primeng

If there is one data it will display only one raw. If there are two data then it will show fore rows, if there are there data then it will display nine rows. I think in my component.ts file is the problem.

data is getting from laravel(Back End)

**itemlist.component.ts**

```js
import { NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from '@root/shared/classes/project';
import { DataService } from '@root/shared/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-list',
  templateUrl: './item-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-list.component.scss']
})
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {

  projects:any;

  project = new Project();

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProjectsData();

  }

  //get project data into the table
  getProjectsData() {
    this.dataService.getProjectData().subscribe(res => {
      this.projects = res;
    })
  }
}
```

**itemlist.component.html**

```
<p-table [value]="projects" styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines" responsiveLayout="scroll" scrollHeight="17.8vw">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.customer <br> itemlist.name</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.project <br> itemlist.name</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.business <br> itemlist.divition</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.rank</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.order <br> itemlist.amount</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" translate>itemlist.customer <br> itemlist.area</th>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body"> 
    <tr *ngFor="let pjt of projects">
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.customer_name }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; width: 15vw;">{{ pjt.project_name_jp }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.business_divition }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.rank }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.order_amount }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ pjt.customer_area }}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: how many times `this.dataService.getProjectData().subscribe()` this method is called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `*ngFor="let pjt of projects"` and use `let` variable.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-pjt>
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vvmqq9?file=src/app/item-list/item-list.component.html)

---

### References

[Table Templating | PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/templating)

---